# How to migrate Ingress Nginx Controller from k8s.gcr.io to registry.k8s.io?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, nginx-ingress, ingress-nginx

I read that the Container Registry called **k8s.gcr.io** is about to be removed soon.
Any container pulls from this repository must migrate to the replacer: **registry.k8s.io**.

How can I change this in GCP GKE for existing workloads that already use the legacy?

Will it cause issues on Ingress IP address, SSL certs, any downtime etc?

Answer (score 2):

As per this official [doc](https://kubernetes.io/blog/2023/03/10/image-registry-redirect/) , k8s.gcr.io will be redirected to registry.k8s.io, following the community announcement. This change will happen gradually to reduce disruption, and should be transparent to the majority of GKE clusters.

> For impacted users that run in a restricted environment, the best
> option is to copy over the required images to a private registry or
> configure a pull-through cache in their registry.
>
> There are several tools to copy images between registries; crane is
> one of those tools, and images can be copied to a private registry by
> using crane copy SRC DST. There are also vendor-specific tools, like
> e.g. Google’s gcrane, that perform a similar function but are
> streamlined for their platform. You can also refer to the options
> listed in the [doc](https://kubernetes.io/blog/2023/03/10/image-registry-redirect/#how-can-i-find-which-images-are-using-the-legacy-registry-and-fix-them) and troubleshoot further.
>
> If you believe you have encountered a bug with the new registry or the
> redirect, please open an issue in the
> [https://github.com/kubernetes/registry.k8s.io/issues](https://github.com/kubernetes/registry.k8s.io/issues/).